# ElasticSearch Latitude and longitude geo_type in mapping file

Tags: elasticsearch

Do the fields need to be explicitly named `lat` and `lon` for `geo_type` mapping to work?
For example, this is my code:

```
public class coordinates {
    private String latitiude;
    private String longitude;
}
```

Sample mapping file in elastic search:

```
"coordinates": {
    "type": "geo_point"
}
```

I get the error:

```
error': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse field [coordinates] of type [geo_point]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'parse_exception', 'reason': 'field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]'}}
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you referred this document ? - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

Comment: yes but that documentation didn't really explain how to tackle my problem. I have came across this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/ingest-processors.html but hoping this is not the only way of tackling this problem